# For real $x$, prove that $x\in\mathbb{Q}\iff-x\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation, rational-numbers

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $x\in \mathbb{Q}\iff-x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

So I am having trouble coming up with an approach to figure out this proof. I feel as if I have the basics covered. I was going to break the $\iff$ into two if then statements. I figured simplifying the problem can potentially provide some insight.

case (1):  $\quad$ If $\phantom{-}x \in\mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow -x \in \mathbb{Q}$
case (2):  $\quad$ If $-x \in\mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow \phantom{-}x \in \mathbb{Q}$

And I begin with the basics:

If $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $x$ can be expressed as a ratio of two integers in lowest terms such that $x=\dfrac{a}{b}$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Now I know that either $a$ or $b$ have to be a negative integer to show that $-x\in\mathbb{Q}$ but this is where I get stuck.

A push in the right direction would be heavily appreciated.

Comment: what is rational number?

Comment: @athos a rational number is one that can be expressed as a ratio of integers in lowest terms where the gcd of the two integers is 1. But I feel as if its wrong just to say if a is negative then -x is in the rational numbers, or saying b is negative and then -x is in the rational numbers.

Comment: then seems it's enough to prove $-(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{-a}{b}$.

Comment: @athos Interesting but what is the logic behind introducing the negative?

Comment: $x=\frac{a}{b}\iff -x = \frac{-a}{b}$ and note that $\frac{-a}{b}$ is also a ratio of two integers and so rational.  The bit about $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is unnecessary here and not actually a part of the definition of rational numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz my issue is that the logic is breaking where we introduce the negative because I assumed we cannot say $-x=\dfrac{-a}{b}$ because that is what we are trying to prove in the first case.

Comment: You are concerned about that iff I used?  Fine then, $-x$ is the additive inverse of $x$.  It is easy to prove that additive inverses are unique in any ring or field.  It is also easy to prove that $(\frac{a}{b})+(\frac{-a}{b})=0$, this is just a matter of arithmetic and the definition of addition in $\Bbb Q$.  It follows then that $x=\frac{a}{b}\iff -x=\frac{-a}{b}$

Comment: Thank you I think the additive inverse comment clicked, I believe I know what to do.

Comment: Generally if $r$ is root of $f(x)$ then $-r$ is a root of $f(-x)$. Your is the special *linear* case $\,f(x) = b\:\!x - a$ $\quad$